# express validator not installing in node

Tags: node.js

i am working on a small node project where i need to install express validator, but it is not installing. MY root file has app.js in which i am importing all deps and a package.json file, apart from index.ejs file. my app.js looks like this:

app.js:

```
 var express = require("express");

 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 var path = require("path");
 var app= express();


 var expressValidator = require("express-validator");
app.use(expressValidator());

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  req.assert(req.body.password,'Enter Password').notEmpty();
})
var errors = req.validationErrors();

 //view engine
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));

 //body-parser:
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


 //app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
 var people=[
 {firstname: "Jeff", lastname: "Murphy", age: 30},
 {firstname: "Thomas", lastname: "Reynolds", age: 21},
 {firstname: "Dan", lastname: "Schneider", age: 22}
 ]

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.render("index",{

     title: "Customers",
     people: people

 });

 app.post("/users/add", function(req,res){
     console.log("form submitted");
     var forminfo = {

         firstname: req.body.firstname,
         lastname: req.body.lastname

     }
     console.log("forminfo: ",forminfo)
 })

 //for parsing arrays use res.json:
 //res.json(people[1].name)


});

app.listen(3000, function(){

    console.log("server set up at port 3000")

})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nod simple test app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "gaurav",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3"

  }
}
```

npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express-validator',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData express-validator
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData express-validator
9 silly mapToRegistry name express-validator
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'express-validator',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'express-validator',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'express-validator',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express-validator
14 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express-validator
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:29:35 PM
17 verbose request id 029d1b0b2e60e388
18 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-validator
19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 2:29:46 PM
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-validator
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 2:30:47 PM
24 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-validator
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for express-validator { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'connect',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   address: '104.18.98.96',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 443 }
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
30 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
30 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
31 verbose cwd D:\angularcls\node\test
32 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express-validator" "--save"
34 error node v6.11.0
35 error npm  v3.10.10
36 error code ECONNREFUSED
37 error errno ECONNREFUSED
38 error syscall connect
39 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
39 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
39 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
39 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
39 error  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.18.98.96:443
39 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
39 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
39 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
39 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
39 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
39 error   syscall: 'connect',
39 error   address: '104.18.98.96',
39 error   port: 443 }
40 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
40 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

as per the debug log, i am on proxy. but i removed the proxy and then again this appears. Please guide me what is wrong.

Comment: How do you run the code?
Is it npm start or node app.js?

Comment: i run by nodemon

Comment: nodemon app.js?